# Mass deleting and single deleting in one page with laravel

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, methods

I got a form where I am able to destroy multiple items by checking a checkbox and able to delete a single item by clicking a delete button in the table row.

Because the single deletion is surrounded with a form, containing a `DELETE` method. I'm not sure how to handle the mass deletion. Cause I guess I'll need a form for that as well.

But because the single deletion has a form, I can't surround with another form.

Also I must have space to use form for filters, which will send the `POST` method.

What is the best solution for this in laravel? I can't use a action, because I need the `DELETE` method..

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Comment: Ye but I would just send it as a normal page, with refresh. I guess you refering to an AJAX call? Not sure how I would do it with Javsacript tho. Would be glad if someone could take me to the right direction. It has to have a DELETE method as well.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Forms work good for simple interactions like editing something or creating a new resource. However when interaction with a list of items and having multiple possible actions it gets complicated (as you noticed). That's were our new best friend AJAX comes in. I'll use jQuery, although you could use plain javascript too (it's just a lot more work)
We'll use the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method to make our calls to the server

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your/target/url',
    type: 'delete',
    data: {ids: [1,2,3]}, // just an example. here you would insert the ids of all selected items
}).done(function(data){
    // gets called if everything goes well 
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    // ooops the request returned an HTTP error code, something bad must have happened
});
```

In your controller you should then be able to access the variable with `Input::get('ids')`

Comment: Ye I've created something like this some seconds ago, imo this is really show.. But I guess this is the best option in this situation. I reload the page on success.

Comment: @guidsen "imo this is really show" do you mean slow?

Comment: Not sure, maybe cause I'm working on localhost. I'm sure it will be faster on a production server anyway. I'll post my implementation in some minutes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this situation by creating a ajax request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).data('url'),
  type: 'POST',
  data: {_method: 'delete', _token: token},
  success: function () {
    //
  }
})
```